# How to suppress a subclass to log messages in Log4Net

Tags: log4net

I have a situation where I am using a seperate copmonent in my application,which is also logging the messages along with my class messages.

Is there a way in log4net to supress this class component from logging messages in the logger.
I cant modify the subclass component.
Can some configurations in the Log4Net suppress this specific class messages.

Answer (score 1):

If your loggers have hierarchical names you can do something like this:

```
<logger name="namespace.YourClassThatShouldNotLog" additivity="false">
   <level value="OFF" />
</logger>

<root>
   <level value="ALL" />
   <appender-ref ref="YourAppender" />
</root>
```

**Edit:** Actually you just need to have a dedicated logger (name) for the class in question. It does not need to be hierarchical.